# Identify the source or client of POST data

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application that accepts User Name as Form Post value, and authenticates based on the posted value.

in Page_Init of my Login.aspx, I have below code

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["username"].ToString()))
{
    //my logic to authenticate, authorize, redirect to page
}
```

It works fine so far. I had to add this because I have an external authentication system in my company which does all authentication part and send user name to the Application accessed to auto-login within the application.

Though it works fine, I want to add an additional layer of security on top of this Posted user name.  I want to identify if this Post request came from our Gateway website.  My questions are

- Is there a way to identify the URL posted to my Login.aspx?
- If not, is there a way to identify any other client information to validate the post?

I don't want anyone who creates a simple HTML with post variable "username" get access to my application.  Thanks for your insights on this.

Is looking at one or both the values in Request.UserHostAddress and Request.UserHostName fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to identify the URL posted to my Login.aspx?

No.

> If not, is there a way to identify any other client information to
>   validate the post?

Well, the only reliable information is the client IP. So if you know the address of the application that will be sending this HTTP request you could use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` to compare against.

As an alternative you could share some common secret between the client application and your server. And then in addition to posting the username, you could require the client to POST some additional message that will be signed with this secret. Now the the server can verify the signature and guarantee that it is coming from the client (because it is the only one who knows how to sign the message). This process is called [`Digital Signature`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) and guarantees that a message hasn't been tampered between a sender and a receiver.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same but wanted to double-confirm it; I hope there is no way anybody could tamper UserHostAddress or UserHostName

Comment: adding secret key makes sense; as my applications are on SSL, i believe it is hard to sniff the traffic

Comment: Yes, SSL is a must in those kind of applications.